# Designing java application on Mac OSX using Java Swing

Tags: java, macos, swing, user-interface

How do I implement this expanded title bar using java swing? I can't seem to find the right control/UI element to add to have the same effect.

Here's what I mean: Notice the extra space under "Keyboard" title containing 3 buttons and one text box?

What I have so far just one line title bar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see any images in your post which makes this a little difficult to help with, but I do have a suggestion based solely on some guessing from what you describe.

It sounds like you are looking for a `GridBagLayout`. That in combination with `GridBagConstraints` will allow you to have multi-line panels with varying numbers of items in each area.

For example, if you want 1 item to have three items below it, then you can set that item to have a `GridBagConstraint.gridwidth=3` which will cause that item to take up three "cells" allowing three individual items to be stored above or below it in the same size of space.

Hope that helps, but its all I can offer with the limited info in the post.

Comment: Ah, so sorry! Here's the link: http://i.imgur.com/aTuTs.png

I've googled GridBagLayout, not sure that is what I want though.

Comment: hmm, that looks tough. Swing usually abstracts away alot of formatting stuff on things like their title bars. If you can set a layout in it, then theoretically the `GridBagLayout` allows you to have multiple rows. But if you cant set the layout or use it like that then you are just going to have to use a panel. You could either combine a titlebar with a panel for the 2 rows, or you might be able to hide the titlebar and just use the panel. only thing is you have to implement all the buttons and click&drag listeners.

Comment: Setting a theme(Look and Feel) might also help. Did you set it to use the native mac look and feel? I dont work with macs so my knowledge goes out the window there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm away from my Mac, but I'd start by trying to add a JToolbar to the JFrame at GridLayout.NORTH - I'd expect the look and feel to render it like your image.